# Search in data showed in rows with 2 columns using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I showed a JSON data using ng-repeat in rows with 2 columns. I also have a search box to filter desired data. my code is as below:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search" />
<div class="row" ng-repeat="x in books | filter:search" ng-if="$index%2==0">
    <div class="col" > 
        {{x.name}}  , {{x.type}} 
    </div>
    <div class="col" > 
        {{books [$index+1].name}}  , {{books [$index+1].type}} `  `   
    </div>
</div>
```

but when I use the search box, the results wont show correctly.
Sometimes it shows both desired data and its next index , sometimes it shows the desired data in both columns of a row and sometimes it shows nothing at all.
How should I make it correct ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the `ng-if="$index%2==0"`

Comment: Create plunker demo that reproduces problem

Comment: If I remove ng-if the rows will be duplicated

Answer (score 0):

$index refers to the index in the *filter results*, but you're using it to access the *original array* in the second inner div. So if you have books A B C in your list, and if you search for A, then the filter results will have one item but the original books array still has all three, and B will still appear because books[1] is B.

Instead of using rows and cols, could you place the ng-repeat on the inner div and wrap them inside a single container that gives you the width you want? If the inner divs use `float: left` or `display: inline-block`, you'd get a two-column list if the container is the right width.

```
<div class="books-container">
    <div class="book" ng-repeat="x in books | filter:search"> 
        {{x.name}}  , {{x.type}} 
    </div>
</div>
```

Working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/MG4do0kqV8wk0nk9tlKJ?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I must have two column rows. IF i use float for divs then where should i put the ng-repeat?